# Moved my site to new host now getting 404

Tags: multisite, permalinks, 404-error, migration, hosting

I just moved my wordpress multisite to a new host and all the pages expect the homepage keep getting the follower error

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have tried resetting the permalinks inside the wp admin that doesn't seem to work.

Could does have something to do that the site was an addon domain on cpanel at my old hsot while its the primary domain in my current cpanel? Please let me know what i can do to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like a message provided by your hoster. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I asked them and they it's not coming from them, I have tried resetting the htacess and looked over the database tables but no luck. I'm previewing the site through the host file could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Add their _complete_ explanation to the question (with an [edit]). Else it's just them being lazy.